# Handle timeout from Host Integration Server

Tags: .net, exception, timeout, cics

I've been searching all around and i can't seem to find any timeout example returned from an HIS.
I have a webservice that consumes an HIS transaction and I'm getting a [Microsoft.HostIntegration.TI.CustomTIException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.hostintegration.ti.customtiexception_members.aspx) when it's a timeout on the transaction (it says on the exception's message).

Is there any way to encapsulate it with an [System.TimeoutException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so I can handle it on my webservice?